# Errors while inserting document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have this strange error

type 0x64 not supported: 00 07 5f 69 64 00

while inserting a document in mongodb. I have googled it but couldn't find the reason behind this error and how to fix it.
Any suggestions.

Comment: what server side language are you using? Also what does your data look like?

Answer (score 0):

The [BSON spec](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification) has a series of available element types. `0x64` is not one of those types.

What driver are you using?

Do you have some sample code that generates this error?

Comment: Hi gates,I am currently using the PHP driver for mongodb. Well actually I am inserting the twitter feeds into the mongodb. The error is random and I can't say that the error is generated at a particular step or document. Looking for insights

Comment: Does the above throw an exception? If it throws an exception, you should be able to pinpoint the exact query where it is failing.